# emacs minitest mode not running in the emacs terminal but fine in the normal terminal

Tags: ruby, emacs, minitest

I am trying to be able to use [mini-test](https://github.com/arthurnn/minitest-emacs) mode to enable me to activate and run my tests directly from emacs.

The relevant ruby part of my ~/.emacs, looks like this:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'robe-mode)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
               '("\\.\\(?:gemspec\\|irbrc\\|gemrc\\|rake\\|rb\\|ru\\|thor\\)\\'" . ruby-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\(Capfile\\|Gemfile\\(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\)?\\|[rR]akefile\\)\\'" . ruby-mode)) 

(require 'minitest)
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'minitest-mode)

(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
          (lambda () (rvm-activate-corresponding-ruby)))
```

Whenever I activate a test by hitting `X-c ,s` I get a segfault.  The dump is at the bottom of this post.

Minitest executes the following line:

```
bundle exec ruby -Ilib\:test\:spec /Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/test/integration/contacts/import_contact_test.rb -ntest_primary_values_set_if_provided
```

If I execute this in my normal terminal then it runs fine but when I activate it in emacs, I get this segfault:

```
/Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/ext/oj/oj.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0010 p:-17526627450910 s:0033 e:000032 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0009 p:---- s:0031 e:000030 CFUNC  :require
c:0008 p:0081 s:0027 e:000026 TOP    /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/lib/oj.rb:34 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0025 e:000024 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0164 s:0021 e:000020 TOP    /Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/app.rb:16 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0014 e:000013 CFUNC  :require_relative
c:0004 p:0081 s:0010 E:0018a8 TOP    /Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/test/test_helper.rb:23 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :require_relative
c:0002 p:0007 s:0004 E:000d78 EVAL   /Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/test/jobs/import_contacts_job_test.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0022b8 TOP    [FINISH]

/Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/test/jobs/import_contacts_job_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
/Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/test/jobs/import_contacts_job_test.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/test/test_helper.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/test/test_helper.rb:23:in `require_relative'
/Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/app.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/app.rb:16:in `require'
/Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/lib/oj.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/lib/oj.rb:34:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /Users/paulcowan/projects/crm/test/jobs/import_contacts_job_test.rb

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb
    4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    6 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
    9 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   10 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   11 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
   15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
   16 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
   18 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/pathname.bundle
   19 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb
   20 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/constants.rb
   21 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
   22 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/etc.bundle
   23 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
   24 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
   25 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
   26 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   27 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
   28 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb
   29 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
   30 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
   31 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
   32 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
   33 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/version.rb
   34 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb
   35 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb
   36 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   37 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/digest.bundle
   38 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/digest.rb
   39 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/digest/sha1.bundle
   40 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb
   41 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb
   42 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
   43 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
   44 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
   45 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/ruby_version.rb
   46 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/source.rb
   47 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb
   48 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb
   49 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ftp.rb
   50 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb
   51 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/https.rb
   52 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldap.rb
   53 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldaps.rb
   54 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/mailto.rb
   55 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri.rb
   56 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/core.rb
   57 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/util.rb
   58 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/cookie.rb
   59 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi.rb
   60 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/socket.bundle
   61 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb
   62 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/fcntl.bundle
   63 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
   64 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/openssl.bundle
   65 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/bn.rb
   66 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/cipher.rb
   67 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/stringio.bundle
   68 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/config.rb
   69 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/digest.rb
   70 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/x509.rb
   71 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb
   72 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb
   73 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb
   74 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/securerandom.rb
   75 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/resolv.rb
   76 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
   77 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/text.rb
   78 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/name_tuple.rb
   79 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
   80 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
   81 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
   82 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
   83 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/strscan.bundle
   84 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
   85 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
   86 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb
   87 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb
   88 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
   89 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb
   90 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
   91 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/index.rb
   92 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
   93 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
   94 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
   95 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb
   96 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb
   97 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/configuration.rb
   98 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/exit_codes.rb
   99 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/multi_json-1.9.2/lib/multi_json/options.rb
  100 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/multi_json-1.9.2/lib/multi_json/version.rb
  101 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/multi_json-1.9.2/lib/multi_json/adapter_error.rb
  102 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/multi_json-1.9.2/lib/multi_json/parse_error.rb
  103 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/multi_json-1.9.2/lib/multi_json.rb
  104 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/json.rb
  105 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/adapters.rb
  106 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/source_file.rb
  107 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/file_list.rb
  108 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/result.rb
  109 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/filter.rb
  110 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/formatter/simple_formatter.rb
  111 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/formatter/multi_formatter.rb
  112 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/formatter.rb
  113 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/last_run.rb
  114 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/merge_helpers.rb
  115 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/result_merger.rb
  116 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/command_guesser.rb
  117 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/version.rb
  118 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb
  119 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/date_core.bundle
  120 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date/format.rb
  121 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date.rb
  122 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/time.rb
  123 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-html-0.7.1/lib/simplecov-html/version.rb
  124 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-html-0.7.1/lib/simplecov-html.rb
  125 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov/defaults.rb
  126 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov.rb
  127 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/coverage.bundle
  128 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/lib/oj/version.rb
  129 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/lib/oj/bag.rb
  130 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/lib/oj/error.rb
  131 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/lib/oj/mimic.rb
  132 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/lib/oj/saj.rb
  133 /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/oj-2.1.4/lib/oj/schandler.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


 abort trap: 6 at Thu Aug 14 05:46:16
```

Comment: have you verified that the ruby version is actually correct? I've run into a lot of issues with rvm and emacs. Even when using rvm-activate-cooresponding-ruby.

Comment: Also look at the github issue's page for oj, there are a handful of closed bugs dealing with segfaults for old versions of oj. Is there any reason you are using a > 1 year old version of oj? I would put on money that upgrading to a recent release of oj will fix your problem.

Comment: Updating oj did not fix the problem.  The thing is that it passes in the normal terminal session but not the emacs terminal emulator.